# PCAP management solution that takes into dynamic traffic?

Tags: linux, bash, pcap

I'm currently trying to find a good solution to a PCAP storage problem I'm encountering.  Right now, I have a LVM drive on RHEL that stores PCAPs taken from netsniff.  As you can imagine, this drive fills up quickly and somewhat unpredictably depending on how much traffic flows across my network.

Currently, I'm using an inelegant solution to my problem.  I'm using a custom shell script that checks the percentage of the disk remaining then removes the 100 oldest captures by invoking logrotate.  This is set to run every 30 minutes or so.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i ALERT
ALERt=80

df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|udev' | awk '{print $1 " " $5}' | while read output;

do
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '%' -f1)
    if [ $partition -ge $ALERT ]; then
        echo "Running Out of Space" $partition"% remaining"
        logrotate -v
    else
        echo "Plenty of Space" $partition"% remaining"
    fi

done
```

I was wondering if there was a better solution out there?  Something that might take into account fluctuations in traffic and adjust the offloading of pcaps accordingly.

Comment: Well, you showed part of your script so you get the benefit of the doubt. If you don't get useful answers, head over to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). The folks at  [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are very good.

Answer (score 0):

What about compressing all the pcaps? This would probably save a lot of space.

Comment: I'll have to test it out, but that's definitely an option.  I'm somewhat resource limited in my setup though.  I'm pretty much saving the PCAPs for further analysis in case I get something interesting on my network.  I run a few honeypots so it happens.